# PHP: file_get_contents doesn't work with certain javascript sites

Tags: javascript, php, curl

Some certain websites return only some of the code/html and not the full page 
e.g.: "https://www.origin.com/deu/de-de/store/mirrors-edge/mirrors-edge-catalyst/standard-edition"

You get the full page when viewing it with the browsers developer tools.

But not with:

- View Page Source
- file_get_contents
- curl_init

Is there any way to get the "real" content?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create a phishing website or something?

Comment: Well, nothing negativ like that^^
I've written myself a "games wishlist" if you will, which can fetch the prices for the games directly from the shops.
Origin worked just like every other site (steam for example), but they changed their shop some time ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use phantomjs. For example:

File test.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://www.origin.com/deu/de-de/store/mirrors-edge/mirrors-edge-catalyst/standard-edition';
page.open(url, function (status) {
console.log(page.content)    
phantom.exit();
```

});

After install phantomjs in your server run command

```
phantomjs test.js
```

**UPDATE**

```
var ok = 'Your needed content';
var iterator = 0;
page.open(url, function(status) {
   setInterval(function () {
       if(page.content.indexOf(ok) > -1) {
          console.log (page.content);
          phantom.exit(0)
       }
       iterator++;
       if(iterator > 50) {
          cosole.log('Bad content');
          phantom.exit(0);
        }
    }, timeInterval)
});
```

Comment: Thx, I've looked into phantomjs and when I write the site into a png I can see the price (which I want to extract).

BUT when writing the data into a text file, the price isn't there?

It's pretty much the same as with file_get_contents ...

Comment: To clarify: if I use the phantom function to write to a file it doesn't work:
`var page = require('webpage').create(), system = require('system'), url;
var fs = require('fs'), system = require('system');

if (system.args.length < 2) {
 console.log ('Usage: test.js URL');
 phantom.exit ();
}

var url = system.args[1];

page.open(url, function(status) {
 if(status === "success") {
  fs.write ("test.dat", page.content, 'w');
 }
 phantom.exit();
});
`

But when "piping" the output in the commandline, I do get the whole page code!
`phantomjs test.js URL > test.dat`

Comment: Use setTimeout for waiting full page content. Or add callback. http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html

Comment: Ok, so I've marked @GardenApple as the working answer, because sometimes it does work.  
Seems as if there might be a timeout; alas I can't figure out how to implement the ResourceReceived callback -> could you pls explain some more?  
Something I found that could help: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

Comment: page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
        if(response.stage =='end' && response.url.indexOf('example.com/price_request')>-1)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){/*do what you want*/}, 500);
            }
    };

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just for completeness sake, here is the code I'm using now:
**PHP**

```
$PhantomTimeout = 5000; // timeout to wait for js-functions on websites like Origin.com
if (parse_url ($_GET["url"], PHP_URL_HOST) == 'www.origin.com')
{
    exec ('phantomjs.exe --ignore-ssl-errors=true --load-images=false fetch_external.js "'.$_GET["url"].'" '.$PhantomTimeout, $DataArr);
    $Data = implode ('\n', $DataArr);
}
```

**JS**

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(), system = require('system'), url;

if (system.args.length < 3) {
    console.log ('Usage: fetch_external.js URL TIMEOUT');
    phantom.exit (1);
}

var url = system.args[1];
var time = system.args[2];

page.open(url, function(status) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log (page.content);
        phantom.exit(0)
    }, time)
});
```

A callback to wait until the whole page is loaded or a specific element would be better, but I haven't found out on how to do that yet...